# How to handle login pop up by using Selenium web driver in google chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to login to the to a particular website using selenium python with chrome driver.

CODE-1

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
location = "url"
driver.get(location)
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.send_keys('username')
alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
alert.send_keys('password')
alert.accept()
```

CODE-2

```
driver.get("https://username:password@url")
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

Comment: Did you try use method accept_alert { ... } ?

Comment: can you share error you getting ?

Comment: I'm not getting any error.. values are not being taken

Comment: @Nedim i dont think we have  accept_alert{} in python.. i cant pass those credentials to that login pop up

Comment: can you share url ?

Comment: what error you getting for code2?